# JavaScript Strings with Compare signs are Ignored?

Tags: javascript, string

I've noticed an issue I've never encountered before. Strings in JavaScript that contain `<` are ignored. Why is that? Here are a few of the results I've noticed:

```
msg = "<This entire string would be ignored."
msg = "This part of the string is ok. <While this part is ignored."
msg = "<This part is ignored> But this half of the string will still print."
```

Is this some kind of special escape character or something? What is it used for? Additionally, what would be a work around for this?

Here is code:

```js
var msg = "This is my message <This is ignored";
document.write(msg);
```

Comment: I don't see the character is getting escaped. Tried in chrome developer console.

Comment: Can't replicate. Could you add a demo?

Comment: You set the `innerHTML` of an element with that string, right? Don't do that. You want to set the `textContent`.

Comment: `<` is used to indicate HTML tags, like `<div>`, `<a>`, etc.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks. I wouldnt think it would do that when contained inside a string?

Comment: Everything you do with `document.write()` is treated as the HTML of the document. What do you expect `document.write("<a href='foo.html'>Click</a>")` to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with JavaScript; it's an issue with your code. Here's the problem, as suggested by @Tomalak.

You are using `innerHTML` as opposed to `textContent`, which will try to parse the string as a tag with attributes, for example.

`<This part is ignored>` → `<this>` with the `part`, `is`, and `ignored` attributes

Comment: It appears that you had a question about it not happening in a string. JavaScript interprets the string, as a string; when you set the `innerHTML` the browser converts it to HTML, but it is still a string in your code. For example: `var msg = '<brendan>'; document.body.innerHTML = msg; console.log(msg);`

Answer (score 1):

When you write something with `document.write()`, it's simply inserted into the HTML source of the page at that location. As a result, if there are any HTML tags in it, they will be parsed. Anything that begins with `<` is treated as an HTML tag. If you want to write a literal `<`, use `&lt;`:

```js
var msg = "This is my message &lt;This is NOT ignored";
document.write(msg);
```

You really shouldn't use `document.write()` in the first place, that's 1990's Javascript; assign to `innerHTML` or `textContent` of an element. `innerHTML` will be parsed as HTML, `textContent` will be treated as literal text and not parsed.